# Solving multiple solution equation in Python

Tags: python, equation-solving

I need to get the solutions of the following trigonometric equation:

[image]

I know there exists either M or M-1 solutions depending on the value of $\Delta$. Does anyone know of any module or algorithm that I can use in Python for this task?

I've tried this way but it is very sensitive to the tolerance and it doesn't work:

```
def f(k, N, d):
    return np.tan(k*(N)) - d*np.sin(k)/(1+d*np.cos(k))
    

k = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 10000+1, endpoint=False)[1:] 

def ksolutions(k,N,d):
    solutions=[]
    tol=4*1e-4
    for i in k:
        if abs(f(i,N,d))<tol:
            solutions.append(i)
    
    print(solutions)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour] and [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).